# File permission in var/www/html/index.html?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, file-permissions

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying 2 get apache2 working. I've just installed apache2 and want to edit var/www/html/index.html however it says I do not have permission to edit or delete. I tried doing `sudo chmod 755 index.html` and it has given me permissions but the file still doesn't allow me to edit or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be under root so doing `su` then doing `chmod 666 index.html` as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions , if you want anyone to be able to read/write this file, it should be sudo `chmod 666 index.html`. By doing `chmod 755` , you can read, write and execute the file as root. Users can read and execute the file, but they cannot write in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to re-access a             `/var/www/html/index.html` file (SSH into a Raspberry Pi). I realised once I changed ownership/write rules via chown command it would consequently not allow me access unless I added sudo i.e. `sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html`.